# How to add floating button on grid image in html & css

Tags: html, css

As shown in the image I have 4 divisions and need to add **view-more** floating button on **image-4** (center of div). how can I do it using HTML & CSS

Note: I need a solution like this:

[image]

**Code:**

```html
<div class="container">
   <div>
    <img> 1 </img>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img> 2 </img>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img> 3 </img>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img> 4 </img>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* CSS */

.container {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
}

.demo button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="demo">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" />
    <button>View-more</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid-item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
.grid-item:first-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.grid-butto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
  </div>
  <button class="grid-butto">buttons</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
button {  
background-color: lightblue;  
color: black;  
font-size: 25px;  
}  
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! for your reply but above solution doesn't help. i dont want to add button inside div, instead i need it on top of img-4

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container::after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image">
    <img> 1 </img>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img> 2 </img>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img> 3 </img>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img> 4 </img>
  </div>

</div>
```